# Efficiency in a service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I got a service that generate the user location.
I got also a thread with the service instance that takes the location from the service and send it to the db.
The thread is sleeping for 1 min and the asking again for the address from the service and sending it to the db.

My question is should I create instead of this thread a service and the second service will be started every 1 min?
The advantage is that the service won't run when he doesn't needs to like the thread but the disadvantage is that I will have to create a new connection every 1 min.

What is better? Who is more efficient?

Comment: why do you have 2 objects in the first place ?

Comment: You mean a service and a thread? to avoid the network on main thread exception.

Comment: but why is the thread sleeping ?

Comment: You ought to be using a DB connection pool.  The cost of acquiring connections will be amortized over all the calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm usually from a line of thought that says that the best is always to not use `Thread.sleep();`

Said that, there're several options you can approach:

. Request location only every 1 minute, but that might have a weird battery impact as the GPS radio will be kept on during the non-working time.

. create a PendingIntent of your service and ask the AlarmManager to call it again in 1 min. This won't be keeping your GPS on all the time (if u program right), but it will need to fix the position again

. you also can in the same service (without destroying and re-starting it) use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to run the thread every 1 min. (GPS ON or OFF depend on programming)

Comment: What is wrost? making the thread sleep every minute for a minute or starting a service every minute that connects to the db. and about requesting a location every 1 min is bad for me since I need to generate the most accurate location in that minute.. in that way I will get one location in 1 min and that the one that will be sent.

Comment: I'm assuming that's a local DB connection, which means making the connection is quick and cheap, so you shouldn't worry with that. So you should set the Location listener to give you updates every minute whenever u call `requestLocationUpdates` and from the Listener callback you spawn a new thread that will put the data on the DB

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a thread or second service to insert the location updates inserted into the database. Why you cant you configure the locationupdates for every 1 minute in requestLocationUpdates method and onLocationChanged event, why cant you directly insert the records into the table. Running a second service or thread every minute might impact your battery performance. I have seen in one of my project.

Comment: That's true my app is eating my battery life. I would like to generate updates every 10 seconds and the most accurate one to send every 1 min. if I will change the requestLocationUpdates to 1min I will get 1 location every 1 min which is bad for me. or I am wrong? *another point is that doing the thread proccess in the service will cause to a network on main thread exception

Comment: I would think, there wont any much difference if you are trying to retrieve the co ordinates using GPS_PROVIDER. How do you make sure out of 6 co ordinates in 1 min which one is accurate? I would prefer to go ahead with 1 minute and save the battery life... The users will be frustrated if the battery is draining more..  If you are fine with my reply, please accept this answer. Thanks

Comment: Right now I'm half convinced, about the battery life I agree with you but about generating every 1 min a location I don't (I hope you can convince me) generating a single update every 1 min might give me a very bad location such as a city level location. About how to calculate the accuracy I havn't finished that part but it's in here:   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html click f3 and look for this line: "Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate". Using a city level location is very bad(and it possible by generating a single location).

Comment: Why do you want to go for singleUpdateLocation, I would suggest you to do requestLocationUpdates and configure the time interval to 1 minute